# SQL Server - code error

Tags: sql-server

I can't understand what is wrong with this code, I am getting an invalid column value error.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [UpdateLocation]
    (@uId varchar(50) = null,
     @currentloc varchar(256) = null,
     @lastloc varchar(256) = null,
     @loggeddate date,
     @loggedtime time)
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT UId FROM Location WHERE UId = @uId)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Location 
        SET CurrentLocation = @currentloc,
            LastLocation = @lastloc,
            LoggedTime = @loggedtime,
            LoggedDate = @loggeddate
        WHERE UId = @uId
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Location (CurrentLocation, LastLocation, LoggedTime, LoggedDate)
        VALUES (@currentloc, @lastloc, @loggedtime, @loggeddate)
    END
END
```

Error :

> Invalid column name `'CurrentLocation'`.

**Tables:**

```
Location
Register
Report
```

**Columns inside table Location:**

```
Id  int 4
UId varchar 50
CurrentLocation varchar 256
LastLocation    varchar 256
LoggedTime  time    5
LoggedDate  date    3
```

Anyone with some solutions?

Comment: Can you post the full error please, with your columns and datatypes.

Comment: Please provide the full error details, including indicating which line causes the problem(s).

Comment: You should post the structure of the tables involved to get a complete view of the issue

Comment: Might be an idea to post your table structure, too

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: are you using ssms? Are you connected to the correct database?

Comment: Try changing your currentloc varchar(256) = null, 
to currentloc varchar(256) = '',
Does this column allow nulls?

Comment: I suspected that you are getting this error when typing the script not when execute it. Press Ctrl + Shift + R in Management Studio.

Comment: @rainman It's when executing

Comment: Are there two tables with the same name in different schemas? Try `SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'Location'`

Comment: Help yourself by helping your reader. Short, cryptic questions and responses are not helpful. What exactly does "It's when executing" mean? When you execute the create script you posted? Or when you execute the procedure? Have you considered asking your DBA or colleagues for guidance?